# Zapier New UI Issue

Tags: zapier

In new Zapier UI, I used to do below..

```js
return z.request(options).then(response => {
  response.throwForStatus();
  const results = z.JSON.parse(response.content);
  let attachmentArray = [];
  attachmentArray = results.data.map(function(result) {
    let attachment = {};
    attachment.id = result.attachment_id;
    let file_url = options.url + `/${attachment.id}`;
    attachment.url = file_url;
    attachment.file = z.dehydrateFile(file_url, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${bundle.authData.access_token}` }
    });
    return attachment;
  });
  return attachmentArray;
});
```

This is my code to provide a trigger. Currently, it throws

`Error: You must pass in a function/array/object. We got string instead.`

Answer (score 0):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team. That error comes from [this line](https://github.com/zapier/zapier-platform-core/blob/7bed19da1e550b76eda250afe6a8fc999478309e/src/tools/resolve-method-path.js#L31-L35), which is responsible for finding methods on your root `App` object. We've actually got a test covering that exact case [here](https://github.com/zapier/zapier-platform-core/blob/b4103016853b08470d5b431b7442b7ffcf313116/test/hydration.js#L30-L37).

The offending code doesn't seem to be in the sample you provided above, but take a look at anywhere you're calling `dehydrate('some str')` or `appTester('some string')`

Comment: I am using the New Zapier UI platform. 
When I removed the below code it works fine.

`attachment.file = z.dehydrateFile(file_url, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${bundle.authData.access_token}` }
    });`
Anything wrong in that function i used ?

Comment: yes. `dehydrateFile` takes a function as its first argument, not a string. See the examples here: https://github.com/zapier/zapier-platform-cli#file-dehydration

Comment: I tried that too. I am getting same error. FYI, I am not using CLI. I am using New Zapier Interface.